# ZeroMQ REQ-ROUTER messages not being received

Tags: kotlin, zeromq, jzmq

I have 10 clients receiving queries from a server, processing the queries and send messages to a server roughly at the same time
The receive side is as such:

I first create the socket:

```
val commandSocket = zmqContext.createSocket(SocketType.ROUTER)
commandSocket.identity = identity.toByteArray()
commandSocket.bind(commandBindAddr)
```

Then send a query as a commands to all clients;

```
for (client in clientsArray) {
            commandSocket.sendMore(client)
            commandSocket.sendMore("")
            commandSocket.send(queryBytes)
            println("command server sent to " + client.decodeToString() )
        }
```

Then I wait for the reply;
....

```
 fun start(): Thread {
        return thread(start=true) {
            println("CommandServer")
            while (true) {
                val addrb = commandSocket.recv()
                val empty = commandSocket.recv()
                val msg = commandSocket.recv()
                println("message received from ${String(addrb)}")
                bq.add(Pair(addrb, msg))
            }
        }
}
```

The client side is as such:
Creating the socket:

```
  val querySocket = zmqContext.createSocket(SocketType.REQ)
            querySocket.identity = identity.toByteArray()
            querySocket.connect(queryAddr)

    fun start(): Thread {
    val serializer = Cbor()

    return thread(start=true) {
        println("QueryProcessor")
        while (true) {
            val recvBytes = querySocket.recv()
            if (recvBytes != null) {
                val q = serializer.load(Query.serializer(), recvBytes)

                val qr = bp.process(q)
                val res = serializer.dump(QueryResponse.serializer(), qr)

                println("$sending query response back")
                querySocket.send(res)
                println("${logTS()} sent to parent")
            } else {
                querySocket.send(null as ByteArray?)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The queries are received and processed by the client and replies are sent back, but as I increase the number of clients, I don't receive messages at the server. It seems that they get somehow lost.

Any idea how to solve this?